# SSH over HTTPS to a server behind a reverse proxy

Tags: docker, security, ssh, https, reverse-proxy

How do I ssh over https through a reverse proxy? I have a docker container running a sshd at port 2222. I can ssh into the container locally with `ssh -i id_rsa -p 2222 10001@localhost` just fine.
Once the docker container is hosted, it sits behind a corporate reverse proxy. The deployment layer allows me to expose one port. I don't have the ability to change the reverse proxy configuration. I know it is running an ISTIO sidecar to handle traffic.

I am running an API on the container as well on port 8080. If I expose 8080 during deployment. I would hit the api with a GET request at `example.com/myapp/` and it would respond with a 200 code.

I changed the exposed port to 2222 and want to ssh into the container. I can't just ssh into the host because it is at the route `/myapp/` behind the reverse proxy `example.com`. I could set up an ssh tunnel from the container to a different vm server that I have ssh access but I am trying to avoid that.

Is there a way to use an https ssh client to connect to the server? Any help is appreciated.

For example the below command

```
ssh -v -i id_rsa -p 2222 10001@example.com/myapp/
```

responds with
`Could not resolve hostname example.com/myapp/: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

I think I need to use netcat like `ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x example.com/myapp/:2222 %h %p` to resolve the proxy. So I do

```
nc -z example.com 443
```

and I get `Connection to example.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!`

Comment: Does it talk HTTP or HTTPS (you could check it with curl)?  You need at least to talk with the correct protocol, ssh alone will not work. Changing the port from 8080 to 2222 will not change anything. Without modifying the endpoint (api) this can't work

Comment: ssh and HTTP are different protocols, and you can't tunnel an ssh connection over an HTTP proxy.

Comment: The following link seam to do similar stuff: [SSH (Reverse) Tunnel Through Websocket](https://rumpelsepp.org/blog/ssh-through-websocket/). I will give it a try.